# Наследуемая модель pydantic в response_model FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

Имеется модель `Task`:

```py
class Task(BaseModel):
    id: str = ''
    author: str
    title: str
    description: str
    created_at: datetime = datetime.now()
```

Хочется иметь `TaskResponse` который будет наследоваться от `Task` и приводить к модели через `response_model` **только с некоторыми нужными полями** для Фронта.

Не работающий ответ от ChatGTP4:

```py
class TaskResponse(Task):
    class Config:
        fields = {'id': ..., 'title': ...}
```

Собственно вопрос в реализации. thx

- fastapi 0.104.0
- pydantic 1.10.13

Comment: Сделайте общую модель, в которой будут перечислены поля, которые есть во всех дочерних моделях, а в дочерних моделях добавляйте специфические для каждой модели поля. А не наоборот, как вы хотите: создать общую модель со всеми полями, "лишние" поля убрать.

Comment: Дробить модель ради этого вообще не вариант

Comment: Ну вы пытаетесь наследование перевернуть с ног на голову. Наследование работает наоборот: есть родитель с какими-то общими свойствами, от него делаете наследование с добавлением дополнительных свойств, эксклюзивных для класса-наследника.

Comment: создайте кастомную модель, не бойтесь нарушать DRY если нарушение только упрощает код "Простое лучше чем сложное" и "Явное лучше чем не явное".